# Adding end-of-string characters to file corrupts it..?

Tags: c, string, file, character

I am creating a shell and am trying to get comment processing to work. I can pass in a text file as a parameter. I have a text file "output" that looks like the following:

```
123
#456
$#789
```

and I want to "end" any strings starting at `'#'` by replacing the `#` with a `'\0'`.

```
int removeComments(char* fileName){ 
   FILE* myfile;
   int c;
   myfile = fopen(fileName, "r+");
   if(myfile == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", fileName);
      exit(-1);
   }

   while((c = fgetc(myfile)) != EOF){

      if(c == '$'){
         c = fgetc(myfile);       // (don't change '$#')
      }
      else if(c == '#'){
         fseek(myfile, -1, SEEK_CUR);
         fputc('\0', myfile);                 //replace '#' with '\0'
         fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_CUR);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If I make it so that I replace `'#'` with `'!'` or any other character, this works fine, changing the file to look like:

```
123
!456
$#789
```

However after I run this code and put in the end-of-string characters, I can no longer open my file, my computer says `"Could not display "output". The file is of an unknown type"`. How can I prevent this? Or if need be, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many editors do not let you open files with '\0' in them. vim for example can show the file. But gedit cannot. You can try the suggestion given in https://superuser.com/questions/246014/use-gedit-to-open-file-with-null-characters.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea. Would it be wise then to copy the file, and then pass the copy with comments into my shell? That way I can still edit the original output file.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, that may not be a bad idea. You can just clear the comments(anything after and include '#') when passing it down in the script. But then retain the original content in the 'output file' if you want to edit that file as it originally was.